# NetTcpBinding across Domains

Tags: c#, wcf, cross-domain, nettcpbinding

I am new to all this, so I don`t even know what questions I should be asking.

- I have a WCF service on Domain A.
- It will be called from Domain B.
- Domain B is not trusted by Domain A.

I'm pretty sure my clientCredentialType can not be "windows".

How do I get them to talk, and authenticate with one another?

Comment: What do you mean by a "windows service" called by Domain B?  Is this a line item in services.msc started by a machine in Domain B?  Is this a Web Service which would export itself and have it's own level of authentication?  Is this something else entirely?  Are the domains in the same forest?

Comment: It's a WCF service, hosted as a windows service.  A computer on another untrusted domain, needs to call it.

Comment: Have a look at [Common Security Scenarios](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730301.aspx) for WCF.  Each scenario includes a diagram, the binding to use, sample code, and config.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that Net Tcp binding with windows authentication will not work between domains that do not trust each other.

You have atleast 2 choices:

- username and password in message header
- a preinstalled certificate

Comment: @ebyrob Federation is a type of trust, I assumed that the asker meant that there was no trust including no federated trust

Comment: Well, Federation can always be added.  I was thinking if he had several such services on various computers it might be worth the trouble to add it.